# TYPO3 7.6.x DMS integration

Tags: typo3, directory, documents, dms

How can I manage Documents, file and folders in TYPO3 7.6.x or can I integrate any DMS in my backend module? I need to manage users, permissions and even create groups of users. I know this is a little too much from TYPO3, but how can I integrate another DMS within it?

Comment: I tried typogorum but when i install it, it crashes with this error:` "Core: Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: require(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/'xxx'/typo3conf/ext/typogorum/ext_tables.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/'xxx'/typo3_src-7.6.16/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/ExtensionManagementUtility.php line 1905"`

Comment: TYPO3 uses [FAL (File abstraction layer)](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/FileAbstractionLayerReference/) for Document management. The core feature handles storage information and file metadata. It works hand in hand with the [user management](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/GettingStartedTutorial/UserManagement/BackendUsers/Index.html) for defining individual user groups, access rights and permissions for the backend as well as the *filestorage*.
In addition, you don't formulate a specific problem, but make an assumption about these features, which proves a lack of research on your side.